# Selecting a database for android

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I was watching android tutorial on databases. They create a class and extend SQLiteOpenHelper. Then they would create a static final string for the database name. When you request a writable database it will always select using the static string. What is the convention used for selecting a different database? Just create another class and extend SQLiteOpenHelper? Also can you pass SQLiteDatabase from one activity to another using intent.putExtra or similar method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the convention used for selecting a different database?

The `SQLiteOpenHelper` handles more than just a database name. It handles schema version, creation, upgrades, etc... So I would expect the convention to be to define another class and extend `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

> Can you pass SQLiteDatabase from one activity to another using intent.putExtra or similar method?

No, you can't. But you can create a new object of the class describing the database (that one that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`, and request a database from it. Internally the `SQLiteOpenHelper` keeps a single writable connection to a database.

Comment: @RandomGuy The SQLite classes aren't a database themselves, but rather represent a connection to the database. You don't need to pass it from one Activity to another because you can just open another connection.